# Angular 9 CORS issue

Tags: angular, cors

I'm migrating my Angular app from 8 to 9 and now I'm getting a CORS issue, which I didn't have before migrating.  How come I don't have this problem with Angular 8 ?

- web runs with ng serve on localhost:4200
- backend runs on localhost (default port 80)

so I've added a `proxy.conf.json` file to my application :

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:80",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

and my `angular.json` looks like :

```
 "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myapp:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
```

Yet, I still get the CORS error when calling the backend. Anything else I should do  ?

I've also tried running the app with the following command `ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.json` but no luck, same error.

**[EDIT]**

After adding `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />` to my backend config, I get this :

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/mybackend/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed.`

But I only added once. I did not added by code either.

**[EDIT 2]**

my config :

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:80/mybackend/",
        "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" },
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
      }
}
```

and I've also removed `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the backend as suggested by @adrisons. Still I get this same error :

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/mybackend/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Is the error actually preventing the response from being received, or is it just showing up in the console? I remember having a similar problem after an upgrade, but the app was actually working fine. It had something to do with an update to chrome that was now logging warnings that was happening before my upgrade, i just didn’t notice them until I was looking in the console.

Comment: Are you setting the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in your back-end? Different port means it's different origin.I know localhost was an exclusion to this rule but most recent version of your browser can change it and start to treat as different origin now.

Comment: @BizzyBob, the response is blocked, so it's not just a warning.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok, I understand but if I use the same browser with Angular 8, it magically works... So I'd be temted to think it is something that changed in Angular.

Comment: What is your backend? .NET?

Comment: @Kiril1512, Yes. I've added  `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` in my web.config, but it does not solve it. Besides I really don't see why I should do that now when it has worked for so long without CORS issues

Comment: @Sam you need to configure this in the middleware. Is this .NET Core or FW?

Comment: @Kiril1512 FW 4.6. But seriously, isn't it strange that if I roll back to Angular 8.1, it suddenly works ??

Comment: @Sam it is not strange because in some part on Angular 9, since the update is big.

Comment: See my EDIT. I have added the header but now the browser complains it is present twice

Comment: You should remove all policies before adding a new one. Add does just that, add. So if another is added elsewhere, there will be two.

Comment: @fredrik yes I had done that by adding a <clear/> before the <add> . Just didn't post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You need to add `changeOrigin` to the proxy. And maybe `pathRewrite`, if you want to remove `/api/` from the target url.

```
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80",
    "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
```

Comment: thanks. my backend is at http://localhost:80/mybackend. What value should I set these parameters to ?

Comment: You could try with `"pathRewrite": { "^/api": "/mybackend"}`

Comment: Copy that config and replace target value to `localhost:80/mybackend`

Comment: Using this config you don't need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header :)

Comment: @adrisons this sounds like it should work... but it doesn't (see my Post edit).

Comment: Try removing `changeOrigin` (option is only necessary if your host target is not the current environment)